# Поиск по нескольким задаваемым параметрам

Tags: delphi, sql

Как сделать запрос SQL на поиск по нескольким задаваемым параметрам? Помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: ты имеешь ввиду SQL-запрос?

Comment: select * from (тут база) where (имя поля)='&#10' and (имя 2 поля)='&#10';  
вроде так, кавычки могут быть двойными, точно не помню.

Comment: Спасибо! Как правильно это связать с ComoBox? Мне надо если текст введен в ComoBox1 и ComoBox2 и ComoBox3 то выводить запрос! Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Приведите задачу полностью...

Comment: На форме 3 ComoBox и DBGrid! 1 ComoBox вид услуги 2 ComoBox количество комнат 3 ComoBox этаж. В ComoBox я выбираю нужные мне параметры нажимаю кнопку Найти и выполняется поиск по базе  по заданным критериям в ComoBox! И все это выводится на DBGrid!

Answer (score 1):

операторами WHERE (Условия) AND (Условия)